# Returning a promise of multiple async functions in a firebase cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a Firebase Cloud Function that calls 2 async functions.

```
exports.someFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('some/path')
  .onCreate(event => {
    asyncFunction1();
    asyncFunction2();
  });
```

Both asyncFunction1 and asyncFunction2 return a promise.

Now, [Firebase dictates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) that we should

> Resolve functions that perform asynchronous processing (also known as "background functions") by returning a JavaScript promise.

However, since my function is performing two asynchronous processes, what should I return? I tried doing

```
exports.someFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('some/path')
  .onCreate(event => {
    return Promise.all(
      asyncFunction1(),
      asyncFunction2()
    );
  });
```

This works: both functions get called and executed correctly, but I also get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined at Function.all` when calling the Cloud Function.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try `Promise.all([asyncFunction1(), asyncFunction2()])`. Look on [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: He is passing arguments without square brackets.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen  The devil is in the detail, :)   `Promise.all` expects an array of promises, not a list of promises in the arguments.